# How to check for a duplicate name in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can you check for a duplicate name in a MySQL? In this instance, for example, this product should not be the same.

```
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "insert purchase.category set id_cat='" & txtID.Text & "', cat_product='" & txtNama.Text & "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Succes")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Dispose()
    End Try

    Load_AddCatPro()
    txtID.Clear()
    txtNama.Clear()

End Sub
```

[image: form]

Comment: try to search first the name using `select` statement if it exist or not then do insert if the name is available

Comment: sql injection for sure. 2nd order but still. Concats are the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for this problem , check this out.

```
    Try
        If txtNama.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Isi Category Product", "Warning",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            With txtID
                .Focus()
                .SelectAll()
            End With
            Exit Sub                    ' tell it to skip the rest
        End If

        cn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from purchase.category where cat_product= '" & txtNama.Text & "'"
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rd.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("Duplicate Entry Found", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            cn.Close()
        Else
            cn.Close()
            cn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "insert purchase.category set id_cat='" & txtID.Text & "', cat_product='" & txtNama.Text & "'"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Data Tersimpan")
            'frmCustomer.DataGridViewCust.Refresh()
            cn.Close()
            Load_AddCatPro()
            txtID.Clear()
            txtNama.Clear()
        End If
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG2xO.png)